# how to check two variables value with match in python?

Tags: python, match

one way for check value of a variable is to use if or two match block but how to check the value with one match block and also check variable value to be in a range in python with match block,  for example this code:

```
somevalue=int(input("enter any number"))
if 10<somevalue<1000:
    print("some message")
```

Comment: the question is : get value from user check the value by match block

Comment: what is a `match block`

Comment: maybe in your native language there are no words for certain things, but that does not mean it is valid english if you leave them out.

Comment: What part of your current code does not work as you expect? Do you have an example of input that you could give and where you'd expect a different result? Also, there is no need to discuss someones ability to write English properly; we all come from different parts of the world.

Comment: @MatsLindh But if the written text is not understandable, and you don't make a remark the text will never be improved by the OP to make it clear what he wants, you do the same

Comment: I think what you are asking is how to return true if a value is within a certain range or less than two values? in your example it would look like `if (n < 100) or (n < 1000): do something` which put more simply would be `if n < 1000: do something`

Comment: @mohsenRostami  The sample code you have provided is valid Python code, and will print "some message" if the user input is > 10 and <  1000, so it is not clear to us what your question or problem is.
  Could you edit your  question to clarify what the problem is and what you're trying to achieve?  Add a longer code example with expected outputs if required to give a clearer example. By 'match block` do you mean how would you do the same test with the match-case functionality introduced in Python 3.10, or does 'match block' = the conditional expression in the if statement?

Comment: so let me append more detail :

Comment: the process is to get number from user and check this value to be greater than 10 and less than 1000 and writing this code by if block is so easy but how to write this code with match case block in python

Comment: Please include the solution with two match blocks in the question.

Answer (score -1):

I think this code is a good alternative to if block that you've written.

```
numbers=list(range(11,1000))
match somevalue:
    case numbers:
        print("some value")
```

Is this something you were looking for?

Answer (score -1):

Something like this? Match-case statements aren't really meant to do this type of thing.

```
match 10 < int(input("enter any number")) < 1000:
    case True:
        print('some message')
```

---

Another possibility of what you're asking for could be:

```
somevalue = int(input("enter any number"))
if somevalue > 10 and somevalue < 1000:
    print('some message')
```

Comment: How is your rewrite of theirs better than theirs? I find theirs clearer and it's probably more efficient, too.

Comment: Uh... Pretty much none of that is true. OP says they can do it with *two* match blocks and they ask how to do it with *one*. I asked them to show their version with two. And I didn't only critique efficiency, I critiqued clarity first. And [few *hundred*](https://tio.run/##RY7BCsIwEETv@Yq5SJMSMLEKKvotUnHVHLINSQT9@pq0FQ@7zM48djd88nPgbh/iON7j4JGdJ5fhfBhiRqRAfRYiJZzRvEvbNXoWW2N@cmOKFoImyBqc8C5lzY9wjNjzg6S1erJVobnA1rTtTtyHiMsf6tRRANVM1UypjkCIjrNMahpqSjWlJQVy2ecdy/llSRpJg1/@SvHMSmENXsh5U7PqbuCEBivIjBaWDkqD6oGZUOP4BQ) isn't "few". Not sure what you mean with "order" of operations.

Comment: Few hundred nanoseconds xD, in what world... also, could you possibly write your timeit any more convoluted? [try 0-30ns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kboPr.png) and not even always faster depending on input.... @KellyBundy

Comment: Your benchmark doesn't do what your answer did.

Comment: hmmk buddy, whatever makes you feel superior